# SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION --Destination in response doesn't match the current URL

Tags: drupal-8, simplesamlphp

I am receiving below error when i try to login from an IDP.

Caused by: Exception: Destination in response doesn't match the current URL. Destination is "**http://example.com**/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/SP", current URL is "**https://example.com:16116**/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/SP".

I am using Drupal 8 and simplesamlphp_auth module.

Answer (score 0):

URL matching in SimpleSAML was very particular.

You do notice that one request is using the protocol prefix 'https, while the other is using 'http'.

Additionally, the port number being reflected could throw it off.

I last worked with this technology a year and a half ago, but we did make use of hostfile switching to target different environemnts, Dev, QA, Production, etc. Avoiding the use of custom ports we had few problems on that front.

Checking the source, you can observe that the Error thrown, stems from a very literal string comparison:

https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/4bbcdd84ebda4c876542af582cac53bbd7056160/modules/saml/lib/Message.php#L585

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for `baseurlpath` value in config.php of SimpleSAMLPHP library.
2. Also cross verify the `RelayState` in authsources.php
3. If required metadata also need to be updated

ref: https://groups.google.com/g/simplesamlphp/c/AcWUojq2aWg